# Multiple problems when upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I initially experienced problems in attempting to upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10, and gave up attempting this.

As a result of these failures, I had to return to factory settings, namely 12.04.

Now, when I try to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04, one or a combination of the following happens, apparently in random order/frequency:

- Password loop when logging on
- Screen freezes on wallpaper setting when I have logged in
- Laptop will not connect to the Internet by wireless (or, it seems, wired) connection

I have tried to solve these problems separately as they have arisen, but with little success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Many thanks for this. I am pretty lousy tech-wise, but can follow instructions such as commands to be used in the terminal etc. Could you provide any information on new release installations and/or upgrade-resistant partitioning?

Answer (score 1):

Is it feasible for you to install 14.10, rather than upgrading to it?  I find upgrading to be frequently problematic.

I moved to a Debian flavor of Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu), because it has rolling releases and never needs to be 'upgraded'.  As a general rule, you should also partition your harddrive so you can perform full install 'upgrades' without affecting your user files/settings/apps/etc.